# application is not able to load assembly 'System.Net.Http' in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using .net framework 4.7.2 and installed System.Net.Http from nuget package. I am using simple asp.net forms application without any API packages.
Application builds without any issue but when I run the application, I get below error.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Here is the full application trace

> Server Error in '/' Application. Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131040) Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Net.Http' or one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Net.Http' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = System.Net.Http  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an
>   assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: System.Net.Http | Domain ID: 4 WRN: A
>   partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is
>   provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect
>   assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual
>   identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name,
>   version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///G:/Projects/Sanganan/eClickShipNew/EasyPost.Web.UI/ LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath =
>   G:\Projects\Sanganan\eClickShipNew\EasyPost.Web.UI\bin Calling
>   assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   G:\Projects\Sanganan\eClickShipNew\EasyPost.Web.UI\web.config LOG:
>   Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Dharmendra\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/vs/67fd7ae1/97340337/System.Net.Http.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/vs/67fd7ae1/97340337/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///G:/Projects/Sanganan/eClickShipNew/EasyPost.Web.UI/bin/System.Net.Http.DLL.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   G:\Projects\Sanganan\eClickShipNew\EasyPost.Web.UI\web.config LOG:
>   Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Dharmendra\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.1.1.3
>   redirected to 4.2.0.0. LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files/vs/67fd7ae1/97340337/System.Net.Http.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files/vs/67fd7ae1/97340337/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///G:/Projects/Sanganan/eClickShipNew/EasyPost.Web.UI/bin/System.Net.Http.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor
>   Version ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).
>   Probing terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http'
>   or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http,
>   Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +36
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +21    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +728
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +196    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +45
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +172
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +91    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +111
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +156
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +695
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +659
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +188
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.7.3190.0

here is the packages.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.12.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" version="4.3.4.13329" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="EasyPost-Official" version="2.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.Common" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.2.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="iTextSharp" version="5.5.13" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.12.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="RestSharp" version="106.5.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension" version="5.2.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Emit" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Security.AccessControl" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Permissions" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Principal.Windows" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Unity" version="5.8.11" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Unity.Abstractions" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Unity.Interception" version="5.5.5" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Check your `package.config`

Comment: Its matching the web.config

Comment: Paste your `package.config`

Comment: updated the main question with config detail

Comment: This line says all you have to change the version from  `<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" to 4.2.0.` or vise versa

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting .NET Framework then you shouldn't need to reference System.Net.Http via a NuGet package. Instead, you should be referencing the framework's System.Net.Http which you can do by right-clicking the References -> Add Reference... and selecting System.Net.Http from the Assemblies -> Framework list.

Comment: This appears to work for my 4.6.2 framework project.  1) remove refs to System.Net.Http;  2) remove nuget packages for System.Net.Http 3) remove bindind redirects in web.config; 4) add system ref (as described above)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. In my case the reference to `System.Net.Http` pointed to some other `.dll` than `.dll`in the `packages` folder. Try to check that the reference is really pointing to the `.dll` file from  `packages` folder